# Adjust WinRT WebView content to control

Tags: webview, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

im trying to fit a Facebook likebox in a webview on a Windows Store APP.

I have done it fine on Android and IOS, just setting the likebox url as html string to the webview.

But in WinRT it shows the box on the upper left corner and A LOT of white space, so the box is really small, i can zoom in to fit it well by hand.

Android and IOS just fit the box in the webview.

Is there any way i can fit it well? also i need to disable user scroll, i only want the user to be able to click the like button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try applying CSS by invoking JS to the loaded webview.

Comment: Im not really good with web programming some example code?